# GH Actions Argo workflow, fails when setting env.var "cant unmarshal obj into Go struct fld Container.spec.templates.container.env of type []v1.EnvVar

Tags: go, kubernetes, github-actions, kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows

```yaml
- name: Generate argo workflow yaml file
  run: |
    helm template  \
      --set image.repository=${{ env.DOCKER_REPOSITORY }} \
      --set image.tag=${TAG} \
      --set env.TEST="TEST" \
      -f backfill/helm/values.yaml $APP_NAME charts/job > workflow-dev.yaml
```

I'm deploying the argo workflow via GH actions. If I remove the `env.TEST`, line the workflow is deployed and works. Also, I'm able to set `env.vars` using the values file; but, when I try to set `env.vars` in the GH actions it gives this error:

> msg="Failed to parse workflow: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Container.spec.templates.container.env of type []v1.EnvVar"

Any idea? I'm stuck on this for some time.

Comment: It would help if this question contained a [mcve] so that we could attempt to reproduce the problem you've described.

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/8827. Looks like you already commented on that. Did you try quoting all the values? What is that `${TAG}` coming from?